# Distinguishability and tagging of particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, identical-particles

I was reading Sakurai's book and here is an extract:

> In classical physics it is possible to keep track of individual particles even though
> they may look alike. When we have particle 1 and particle 2 considered as a
> system, we can, in principle, follow the trajectory of 1 and that of 2 separately at
> each instant of time. For bookkeeping purposes, you may color one of them blue
> and the other red and then examine how the red particle moves and how the blue
> particle moves as time passes.
> In quantum mechanics, however, identical particles are truly indistinguishable.
> This is because we cannot specify more than a complete set of commuting observables for each of the particles; in particular, we cannot label the particle by
> coloring it blue. Nor can we follow the trajectory because that would entail a
> position measurement at each instant of time, which necessarily disturbs the system; in particular, the two situations (a) and (b) shown in Figure 7.1 cannot be
> distinguished-not even in principle.

From this I understand two points (maybe not entirely independent of each other):

1. Since classically you can track the trajectory, in order to distinguish a particle from another you can just "follow" that particle. For instance, a particle formed at LHC can be followed and hence at any instant of time can be distinguished. This cannot be done quantum mechanically, so bye-bye to trying to distinguish by following its trajectory.
2. It is mentioned that a particle cannot be tagged "blue" or "red". What does this tagging exactly mean?
   Four quantum numbers specify an electron, does this tagging mean somehow introducing new such degrees?

To put my question in perspective, I think of something in these lines. Take two identical electrons, put them in separate 1D boxes. Pour "blue" stuff in the whole of 1 box. Pour "red" stuff in the other. Now take them out of these boxes. Will we not able to distinguish between them now? Of course, this would only make sense if we know what we mean by "coloring". So to sum up my question:

What would tagging of particles even mean?  and if it has a sensible meaning what's wrong with my example?  (This is probably related to "we cannot specify more than a complete set of commuting observables for each of the particles" but I do not understand this.)

Answer (score 6):

You're pretty much spot on by raising the question of what "coloring" means. Let's say our classical intuition about particles comes from thinking about rocks that you and your friends throw around. If you paint some color on the rocks and keep throwing them the way you used to, you don't think that the coloring process changes anything fundamental about the rocks. It's the same rocks, but maybe now you can find out which of your friends just hit you with a rock.

This also holds true mathematically. If you trace the movement of the earth around the sun, a good simplification is to think about two points with different masses interacting by gravitation. You can label one of them as, say, "A" for the sun and the other as the "B" for the earth and distinguish them by their masses. But even if they had the same masses, and thus were physically identical in this picture, you are at liberty of naming one "A" and the other "B" and you can track the motion of "A" and "B" in your mathematical model of this system, which means that if you calculate the state of the system at a later time, you will find two point masses at different locations in space, but there is still a unique way of telling which point mass was "A" and which was "B" at the original time. The names "A" and "B" are strapped on the particle without any influence on the physics, much like paint brushed on rocks.

In quantum mechanics, this intuition fails. First of all, because the process of painting without changing physics doesn't have a counterpart in QM. There is no property you can add to one particle to make it more traceable. You can do this for particles as small as large molecules and consider them as classical particles (molecular dyes are for example used in soft matter physics). But when you talk about fundamentally quantum particles like electrons, this is bound to fail, because their fundamental interactions are fixed and introducing a dye means to introduce a new interaction into the system. Also, on a very literal level, single atoms and anything smaller doesn't show color (https://www.fnal.gov/pub/science/inquiring/questions/colorofatoms.html).

This is, I think, what Sakurai means when he says that one cannot specify more than a complete set of commuting observables for a particle: there is no further (commuting) property of the particle that could be strapped to it and would serve as some kind of label while changing nothing about the physical process. Indeed, it is hard to imagine what it should mean to color an electron. It's a point particle, so there is no form of irregularity one can stick a coloring dye to.

And this is also rooted in the mathematical description of quantum systems. When talking about wave functions in the Schrödinger picture of QM, one must use the spin statistics theorem (which is, despite the name, a postulate in classical quantum mechanics and can only be derived as an actual theorem when using quantum field theory as an underlying Lorentz covariant theory). The statement is that a wave function $\Psi_0(x_1,x_2)$ that represents an initial state of a system of two identical particles at time $t=t_i$ is (anti-)symmetric with respect to interchanging the two particles,
$$\Psi_{t_i}(x_1,x_2) = \pm \Psi_{t_i}(x_2,x_1).$$
Now, if, as before, we want to look at a state at a later time $t = t_f > t_i$, which is represented by the wave function $\Psi_{t_f}(x_1,x_2)$ satisfying
$$\Psi_{t_f}(x_1,x_2) = \pm \Psi_{t_f}(x_2,x_1).$$
While there is the probability interpretation of the wave function $\rho_t(x_1,x_2)\textrm{d}x_1\textrm{d}x_2 = |\Psi_t(x_1,x_2)|^2\textrm{d}x_1\textrm{d}x_2$, which can be read as "the probability of finding particle 1 at $x_1$ and the probability of finding particle 2 at $x_2$" (more exactly, in small volumes around $x_1$ and $x_2$), there really isn't a way of distinguishing "the probability of finding particle 1 at $x_1$ and the probability of finding particle 2 at $x_2$" from "the probability of finding particle 1 at $x_2$ and the probability of finding particle 2 at $x_1$". Even if one had in some way found a way to fix this meaning at the initial time $t_i$, there is no way of knowing from the state at $t_f$ which particle should be assigned to $x_1$ and $x_2$ because of the symmetry.

Comment: Yes I was thinking on these lines. Though what about histories? I haven't come across any such thing but its probably a food for thought. What I mean by histories is to compare an electron formed at Big Bang to an electron formed yesterday. The one formed at Big Bang has a longer history so to say. Is there a mechanism in QM that encodes this additional information? Since certainly, an electron formed at Big Bang is physically older and has been existent at those points of time when the latter electron was not existing.

Comment: Obviously classically, you can explicitly find time $t$ etc but I guess I mean something of this sort or maybe different that somehow encodes the longer lifespan of an electron.

Comment: There is a fantastically weird idea that there's just one electron in the universe that just goes back and forth in time, put forward by Wheeler in a phone call to Feynman. If they are all the same electron, they can't be told apart, right?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-electron_universe

Comment: Yes I loved that idea of Wheeler. Ofcourse the numbers of particles and antiparticles don't match. But anyways, this interpretation wasn't  what I had in mind exactly.

Comment: I put this forward to show that talking about *this* electron that was created at the Big Bang compared to *this* electron that was created a minute ago in my homemade particle collider is not a meaningful distinction. There is virtually no way of labelling an electron at the Big Bang and knowing where it is right now. In a not-too-esoteric sense, those two electrons could be considered to literally be the exact same entity.

Comment: Ya I know this and it seems a little counter-intuitive to me. Well what can be done. Its just that probably. Well, still the one created at a collider right now is atleast confined within the collider compared to another far away. This somwewhat tells the difference even though both are identical probably. Thats why I asked maybe there could be a way to encode that information in their wavefunctions. As to how old they were compared to their creation ( Obviously if its not a one-electron universe :) )

Comment: Your answer pretty much answers my question though. Which is *there is no way to add another property  etc* to tag the electrons so tagging itself doesn't make sense in QM. Just waiting for some more answers, they might provide further insight.

Comment: @Lost Most of the anti-electrons are just in a cluster 10^100 light years away.  In 10^10^10 years when everything bounces we'll be back together again.  (this is a joke example of how we could still have 1 electron)

Comment: @Lost Getting back to histories: If you were able to tell the difference between an electron that was created at the Big Bang and never annihilated in any way and one that's fresh out of the collider, this would mean that electrons could age. This isn't impossible to think about. DNA can age, why not electrons? Well, this would entail a quantum number of age. But what would that be and how would we measure it? Electrons can't have kinks or wrinkles. They can't even decay as free particles (because they are the lightest charged particles).

Comment: You could work your way around by saying: Fine, they don't change their own properties, but maybe the interactions they take part in are weakened. But their interactions are (among others) described by shooting photons back and forth. That would mean that the photons need to change their properties. So do photons age? Actually, this is an intersting question (https://www.abc.net.au/science/articles/2014/09/23/4085961.htm). However, even if there was some change over time, it would affect all electrons equally. "Older" electrons wouldn't shoot "older" photons. They all shoot the same photons.

Comment: I was particularly thinking on these lines. Thanks for the resource.

Answer (score 3):

1. indeed, having distinct continuous trajectories means we can distinguish particles. In quantum theory there are no trajectories so this method is not available.
2. tagging means the particles have and carry some property by which we can distinguish them: for example, we can distinguish electron and proton by their mass. Then we operate with a model of the system where "particle 1 is at $\mathbf x_1$ and particle 2 is at $\mathbf x_2$" is a meaningful statement: we can check validity of this statement in principle by looking at the tag.

This is how Schroedinger's equation for many electron atoms is
introduced - electrons are tagged by index $k$, and psi function
depends on *their* coordinates $\mathbf r_k$. Then it is customary to argue that because we can't tag and check which electron has which tag (masses are the same, charges are the same...), this indistinguishability should be preserved also by the state vector (psi function) in the calculations.

Let there be an asymmetric function $f(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)$. Then psi function $\psi(\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2) = f(\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2)$ implies different predictions than $\psi(\mathbf r_1,\mathbf r_2) = f(\mathbf r_2,\mathbf r_1)$ does. So $f$ and both psi functions should be rejected. Otherwise we could distinguish the particles *in the calculations* based on the $\psi$ function.

Comment: Yes I understand all that. What I am interested is whether there is way of tagging two electrons in QM at all. Since what would that even mean? Could there be any extra property (degree of freedom etc) that we can introduce to an electron to make it distinguable? I think @TBissinger touched on that issue a little.

Comment: Also I think I have not understood the impact of your last statement fully. Do you mean something subtle with it where you have italicized ? Maybe shed more light on it then.

Comment: There is no way to put tags on electrons (that we know of) but mathematically there could be such property. Mass or charge of each electron could be found  in future to be close but unique for each particle. Regardless of that, electrons can still be distinguished experimentally now in some cases, such as when they are far apart or they pass through exclusive paths. Indistinguishability (special conditions on psi functions) is well established only for electrons that are close enough so they interact and are part of one quantum system, such as many electron atoms.

Comment: The italics stresses the point that indistinguishability in calculations (implied by special $\psi$) is a different thing than indistinguishability in experiment or in principle.

Comment: Oh, I think I got it. So basically what you say in the second comment is that while doing calculations there is no way to prefer one electron over another but in experiments, such two electrons can still be distinguished, of course, subject to the first condition that they will behave exactly the same only modifying in accordance with the experimental condition or constraints. Did I interpret it correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't understand you after "of course,...". Let me say my point differently: there are different kinds of indistinguishability. In QT the traditional argument is: in atom we cannot follow electrons and they don't have tags, so they are indistinguishable particles, and this assumption imposes constraints on allowed psi functions.

Comment: This constraint is: only those psi functions are allowed which do not enable us to distinguish between particles in calculations or predictions based on those. You can call it "indistinguishability in the psi function" or "in the model".

Comment: If you think about it a lot it comes to mind that the result does not really require the premise. The particles could be still distinguishable in principle (slightly different massess), but the if the differences are very small the allowed psi functions could still be restricted to those same functions (symmetric and antisymmetric). The only solid claim is that the restriction on psi functions is needed to obtain the best results (in quantum chemistry) and works very well.

Comment: @JánLalinský If am I getting it right, your last sentence says that if we had two competing wavefunctions we could rule out one based on which of the two was consistent with the indexing (labelling) and predictions?

Comment: @Anton what you're saying is general rule we should follow, if we had to choose the best psi function. My sentence was specifically about choosing the anti-symmetric psi function instead of non-anti-symmetric psi function - the anti-symmetric psi function gives much better results for electrons.