# How can time dilation make two photons move at the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, time-dilation

So I'm goin down the highway at 25mph and there's a photon moving the same direction I am (ridden by Klaus) and a photon moving the opposite direction (ridden by Steff). I know Klaus and Steff have to be moving at the speed of light from my perspective, but how does time dilate for this to happen? It seems like Steff needs to slow down and thus time needs to speed up for me, but Klaus needs to speed up and thus time needs to slow down for me. How is time dilation able to make Klaus and Steff both appear to be moving at the speed of light from my perspective?

Sorry for good illustration

[image: Me, Klaus, and Steff dilate time]

Comment: This is backwards. That all inertial observers measure the same speed of light is the basic postulate of relativity. Time dilation and other such effects are a *consequence* of that, not a cause of it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity

Comment: What does this picture have to do with anything? Most of it is random and unnecessary.

Comment: BTW, nothing can be at rest relative to a photon, so Klaus & Steff can't ride photons, but I guess you can name the photons themselves Klaus & Steff, if you want.

Comment: @PM2Ring don't you usually name your photons? I do. It makes me feel like I have friends.

Comment: @kaylimekay I've tried, but photons have terrible memories, so they don't remember the names I give them. And there's no way to attach name tags to them, as recently discussed here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605386/123208 :)

Comment: @PM2Ring to which extent this relates to the question (beside the fact that the question is backwards)? This is not a critic, but a genuine question. I know ph are indistinguishable, but we can nevertheless depict the situation as described. It is because because the two photons are separated? Perhaps I am overthinking....

Comment: @Alchimista Particle indistinguishability isn't really relevant to the OP's question. My original comment to the OP was about the fact that photons don't have rest frames, which is always important to emphasise to people who are starting to learn SR.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, but why we can call them Steff and Klaus, in this context?

Comment: @Alchimista They're the OP's photons, he can call them anything he wants. ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Time dilation is one of the *consequences* of a constant speed of light and not the cause for it.**

If we assume $c$ to be constant and then move at some photons emitted towards us, one would think that the velocity of these photons would be greater than $c$. So in order to still have them moving at $v=c$, time "has to" slow down by just the factor that their velocity is $c$.

Of course this is not the actual cause for why time dilation happens, but it might give you some intuitive understanding.