# Why can't particles "remember" the past?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, thought-experiment

The question pertains to a point in Feynman Lectures, Vol III, [5 - 3](https://feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_05.html#Ch5-S3), which is :

> We want to know whether all those that get through $T$ also get through $S′$. They do not. Once they have been filtered by $T$, they do not remember in any way that they were in a $(+S)$ state when they entered $T$.

In this we have two idealized Stern-Gerlach filters ($S$ and $T$) which are maintained at an angle $\alpha$ with respect to each other. We are concerned with the output when we keep a third filter ($S'$), identical to $S$. It is mentioned that the probability amplitude of an output when particles travel from $S$ to $T$, $\langle S | T \rangle \neq \langle T | S' \rangle = \langle T | S \rangle$.

What confuses me is, since the angle between $S$, $T$ and $T$, $S'$ is the same ($\alpha$), shouldn't both ways give the same probability amplitude, considering the **symmetry** of the arrangement? Or am I missing something?

In either ways if it were true that $\langle S | T \rangle = \langle T | S\rangle$, is it possible that the particles hold information (in the sense that we can calculate) about which state it came out of from the $S$ filter even after passing through $S'$?

Comment: I guess the whole question came about because I forgot to consider the "independence" of events by its mathematical definition in probability

Comment: Conversely, our model has to reflect the observation that a particle doesn't have a memory. This is connected with the notion of indistinguishability; here's a recent question on that topic: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/605386/123208

Answer (score 3):

Be careful to distinguish between probability *amplitudes*, which are complex numbers, and probabilities, which are real numbers. For two states $\left|S\right>$ and $\left|T\right>$ we have

$\left<T|S\right> = \left<S|T\right>^*$

So, in general, the probability *amplitudes* $\left<T|S\right>$ and  $\left<S|T\right>$ are not equal, since they are complex conjugates of one another. But the *probabilities* $|\left<T|S\right>|^2$ and $|\left<S|T\right>|^2$ are equal.

A single measurement or observation which collapses the quantum state into an eigenstate of the measurement operator (in this case, an eigenstate of the filter) removes all information about the quantum state before the measurement (except that we know the previous state cannot have been exactly orthogonal to the new state).